# Phone unable to compile shader

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, shader

I have a project I'm working on in libGDX. I'm running tests on a distance field font and I've run into issues while compiling the shader on my Android phone (Galaxy Core 2 4.4.2). When deployed on my phone I get errors while the desktop app works fine (mostly - I'll get to that).

I'll take you through what I've been trying.

I want to be able to enable and disable having a font border during run time, and I can do this fine on the desktop app using the following shader and methods.

.frag:

```
#ifdef GL_ES

precision mediump float;
#else
#define LOWP
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform float u_lower;
uniform float u_upper;

varying vec4 v_color;
uniform vec4 u_outlineColor;
uniform float u_enableOutline;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

const float smoothing = 1.0/12.0;

const float outlineWidth = 3.0/12.0; //will need to be tweaked
const float outerEdgeCenter = 0.5 - outlineWidth; //for optimizing below calculation

void main() {

    float distance = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a;    

    if (u_enableOutline > 0){
        float alpha = smoothstep(outerEdgeCenter - smoothing, outerEdgeCenter + smoothing, distance);//Bigger to accomodate outline
        float border = smoothstep(0.45 - smoothing, 0.55 + smoothing, distance);
        gl_FragColor = vec4( mix(u_outlineColor.rgb, v_color.rgb, border), alpha );
    }
    else{
        float alpha = smoothstep(0.5 - smoothing, 0.5 + smoothing, distance);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color.rgb, alpha);
    }   
}
```

.vert:

```
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
attribute vec4 a_color;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {


    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord0;
    v_color = a_color;

}
```

With the distance font method to enable / disable the outline being:

```
public void enableOutline(float enable) {
        ENABLE_OUTLINE = enable;
}
```

Where ENABLE_OUTLINE is passed to the shader by

```
distanceFieldShader.setUniformf("u_enableOutline", ENABLE_OUTLINE);
```

In this set up, running on my phone gives the following error:

```
"cannot compare float to int"
```

referencing this line in the .frag

```
if (u_enableOutline > 0){
```

Fair enough I say, so I change the data type like so:

```
uniform int u_enableOutline;
```

And the method to pass through an int:

```
public void enableOutline(int enable) {
        ENABLE_OUTLINE = enable;
}
```

BUT there is no way to pass an int to the shader (which is why I chose to use floats, see this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsg98.jpg) and because of this my method to enable the outline doesn't work due to mixing up data types.

So my question is: can I get around this somehow so that I can enable and disable a border on my phone given these constraints?

Comment: and if you try `if (u_enableOutline > 0f){`

Comment: and besides that there should also be a setUniformi version which takes ints

Comment: It should compile if you use 0.0 instead of 0 in your comparison.

Comment: I tried using `0f` but it also produced a syntax error on Android. Specifying `0.0` instead solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the API you are using does not offer you the possibility to use bool and int as Uniforms. The solution of using floats to circumvent this seems to be a good idea.

In your example, the problem you are having is because, unlike C and java, the GLSL compiler does not implicitly convert ints to floats.

what you need to do, is tell the compiler the type of your "0".

By using the syntax, 0.0, the compiler knows that your constant is a float and not an integer.

```
if (u_enableOutline > 0.0){
```

should fix your problem

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I tried using `0f` but that also produced an error. I didn't think to format it as `0.0`.

Comment: Yes GLSL's syntax can be a little tricky especially if you are used to java and C. I use this nice tool to validate my fragment shaders : https://www.shadertoy.com/new . It will not work for vertex shaders but it helps validate syntax.